# Timezone offset is not same in server side and client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timezone-offset

I am working on a web application where date time store in database in UTC. Now when I retrieve the date time to show in UI then I have to convert the date time to the specific time from where the user in using the application.

To convert the time from UTC to specific local time I was doing some demo research. I found two way to convert the time. One is from server side and another is from client side. In server side I am using ASP.NET and in client side I am using JavaScript. But the problem is that the answers are not same.

I am giving the code.

Server side:

```
Label1.Text = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).ToString();
```

Client side:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    $('#Label1').text(offset / 60);
});
```

In the case of server side code it is showing 05:30:00 in the label.
In the case of client side code it is showing -5.5 in the label.

My question is why this two UTC offset is not same ??

Comment: [Timezone offset](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26) in javascript is minutes to add to the local time to get UTC. Also, offsets are not even hours, some have half hours and at least one has 15 minutes. The best way to pass time is to use the timevalue (e.g. `date.getTime()`) as it returns ms since epoch in UTC and can be given to the date constructor to get equivalent local date and time values.

Answer (score 1):

The offsets are formatted differently.
The server-side sample appears to be a `Date`-like object. The client-side version appears to be a `int` (`330`).

The values in these appear to match, though.

Looking at [the specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset.aspx), your server-side code returns a `TimeSpan` object, [while your JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) does indeed return a integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a formatting thing. If your offset is +5:30 then `getTimezoneOffset` will return 330, which is the minutes to add to your local time to get UTC.

If you are passing the time as a value of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z then you can give that directly to the Date constructor:

```
var localDate = new Date(timevalue);
```

To return an equivalent UTC time value, use `getTime`:

```
var UTCTimeValue = localDate.getTime();
```

Javascript date objects use a UTC time value with the system timezone offset to return local date and time values (e.g. for [getDate](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.14), [getHours](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.18), etc.), or UTC values if UTC methods are called (such as [getUTCDate](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.15), [getUTCHours](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.19), etc.).